# Twig: How to debug _context?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

According to https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html, "`_context` references the current context". To better understand this and the twig code in an existing project, I did

```
<div>{{ _context }}</div>
```

The page turns blank. Looks like `_context` is too much to be rendered.
Since I am trying to understand someone else's code, I have no clue what this `_context` could be. Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: In short, it contains all the variables passed/available to the template except `_self` (template filename) and `_charset` (character set of the page)

Answer (score 1):

Use dump to debug, like:

```
{{ dump(_context) }}
```